# Events 1030 and 1006 in Windows 2003

Tags: windows-server-2003, group-policy

I've got a computer running Windows 2003 R2 Standard Edition Service Pack 2 and periodically (every 5 minutes) the systems generates 2 errors that can be seen in the event viewer. The codes of the events are 1030, 1006 that seems to be related to group policies... I don´t know if these events are realted to the perfomance of the system but anyway i would like to fix them.

I've googled around and seems to be a common problem but i haven't found a solution for these events.

Do you know how can be fix it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The event ID's aren't enough information for us to help you. Please edit your post to include the event sources and, if possible, copy and paste the description text.

Answer (score 0):

We had soemthing similar, and in the end had to modify Kerberos to run over TCP and not UDP.  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/244474 gives some information on how to do this.